# Publishing Infopath/Workflow form updates

Tags: workflow, infopath

I've got a simple update to a workflow association/initiation form that isn't deploying correctly. I am setting a tooltip on a validation but when I deploy my updated solution package the change isn't reflected via the UI.

Steps so far:

- Checked file in 14-hive, this is the correct, updated version
- Checked file in the /sitecollection/WorkflowForms folder. It's using the file off disk (14 hive)

When I run stsadm -upgradeformtemplate (and the powershell equivalent) I get this error

> Install-SPInfoPathFormTemplate : The
>   following form template cannot be
>   upgraded because it is not currently
>   uploaded on this farm

Answer (score 0):

If your form does not have any workflows initiated, deactivate the form feature, remove the template and reupload.

Comment: Ah, the form does have workflows initiated, hence my desire to have it updateable. Using upgrade-spsolution is pretty important to my situation (workflow is in production).

Answer (score 0):

I remember having similar issues with the lifecycle of a custom workflow. I have found it difficult to recreate the scenario of workflows designed in SharePoint Designer: if you publish your workflow, it will handle the versioning. With custom workflows, it works differently.

How I circumvated the issue: I left the running workflows alone and I gave the updated version a new GUID and deployed that version. Then I disabled the older versions of the workflow so only the latest version of the workflow will be triggered. After some time, when the old version of the workflow isn't used anymore, I deleted that version from SharePoint.

If you do something similar, it should help you out.